# how to create an options menu at the bottom of the device nexus

Tags: android, menu, android-optionsmenu

I have a problem, I would make an application without actionbar but I would still put a options menu. On devices that have a physical key, do not show the problem, but on devices like the galaxy nexus, yes. How can I make a options menu that appears in the bottom of the screen? To help you understand I put a picture below.

Thanks in advance for the answers

rebus

image: http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/8291/2tzc.jpg

Comment: The problem is that if I create a menu and then put on a full screen on the nexus device, I do not know how to access the menu (because they have no physical button for the menu), the image that I put is what I want to do but do not I can

Answer (score 2):

If you set either minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to 11 or higher, the system will not add the legacy overflow button.

Otherwise, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running on Android 3.0 or higher.

The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower, set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

you have a problem on nexus Since your minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion is 11 or higher

To solve your problem  Change your  targetSdkVersion  to 10

This will solve the issue with Nexus Devices

Comment: I had the same problem: using minimum as 9, and target as 11 (in order the application to appear in google play as compatible with pad-sized devices). I didn't use Any traces of ActionBar, but still wasn't able to display the little dots. Any clues?